# Isn't calculating the group operation on a free group a morphism that should be in bijection some function of the set that it's modeled on?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've been considering the adjunction between the construction of a free group and forgetful functor just as meaning there is a bijection between other objects in **set** and **grp**: maps to/from the group from other groups are isomorphic to maps to/from the set from other sets. Without an operation defined on the set, how's there going to also exist an adjoint to/from computing the group operation if there is one?

Comment: I think you have the adjunction backwards. Maps _from_ the free group $FX$ are the same thing as maps _from_ the set $X$ to some underlying set of a group $UG$. You might be thinking of the [unit and counit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unit+of+an+adjunction) (see also [here](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/what-is-an-adjunction-part-2)), which give you functions $X \to UFX$ and $FUG \to G$. If you want, I can expand this into an answer later tonight.

Comment: Yes please; I see it isn't in either direction now but I still am not familiar with a forgetful functor *of the group operation* compared to forgetful functor *of morphisms from the group* or the other way around: functors from *non-existant operation on the set* to *operations on the group* compared to *functors from functions between the sets*?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "an adjoint to/from computing the group operation if there is one".

Comment: Alright given a category of groups and morphisms between each group, there ought to be morphisms representing the group operation. Where would that group operation go to after the adjoint functor is applied?

Comment: "there ought to be morphisms representing the group operation" Why do you say that?

Comment: I self study for the most part and the information just comes all too much at once on occasion. So coincidentally I wouldn't have calculated if the addition operation on say "$4+1 \rightarrow 5"$ from for example is even a morphism of groups or not. I just have attended seminars, even a schubert calculus workshop that are motivation for continuing math such as quantum algebra & other things that presume a lot of basic information.

Comment: I think I can answer the question now: the functor from **set** to **grp**, is not full or faithful functor or it only should take a *subset* of functions in **set** which are in bijection with group homomorphisms in **grp**... how is that?